# Extract subarray of Columns from a multidimensional array and mutate the original array to remove those columns JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, v8

I want to extract a subarray of `Columns` from a multidimensional array and mutate the original array to remove those columns in JavaScript

Ex: If I have an array

```
originalArray =
[
 [A, B, C, D, E, F],
 [a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,f1],
 [a2,b2,c2,d2,e2,f2],
 [a3,b3,c3,d3,e3,f3]
[
```

Where `A,B,C,D,E,F` are headers
and I want to extract columns [4,0,3] in this order I would get

```
subArray =
[
 [E, A, D],
 [e1,a1,d1],
 [e2,a2,d2],
 [e3,a3,d3]
[


originalArray = 
[
 [B, C, F],
 [b1,c1,f1],
 [b2,c2,f2],
 [b3,c3,f3]
[
```

I found this:
[Extract subarray from a multidimensional array and mutate the original array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69801226/extract-subarray-from-a-multidimensional-array-and-mutate-the-original-array)

which does this for rows

```
let subArray = originalArray.reduce((accumulator, current, index) => {
    if (idxList.includes(index)) {
      //if the current index is included in the idxList array, 
      //push the current value to the accumulator
      accumulator.push(current);
    } else {
      //push the current value to the `tempArray`.
      tempArray.push(current)
    }
    return accumulator;
  }, []);
```

Then I will concatenate these two arrays

reorderedArray = [...subArray, ...originalArray]

Reduce seems like an interesting approach and it seems like it should be a simple fix but I have to admit I am having a hard time understanding `Reduce`

Thanks in advance for your assistance

Comment: `reduce` is really overcomplicated here. Especially because it also uses `tempArray`, not just the `accumulator`. Rewrite it into a normal `for` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add the missing indices to `order` and map the array by mapping nested array with the indices of order.

```js
let
    data = [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'], ['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd1', 'e1', 'f1'], ['a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd2', 'e2', 'f2'], ['a3', 'b3', 'c3', 'd3', 'e3', 'f3']],
    order = [4, 0, 3],
    seen = new Set(order),
    i = 0;

while (order.length < data[0].length) {
    while (seen.has(i)) ++i;
    order.push(i++);
}

data = data.map(a => order.map(i => a[i]));

data.forEach(a => console.log(...a));
```

Comment: wow, that is efficient. Thank you Nina

Answer (score 1):

regular mapping seems like it would work:

```
function myFunction() {
  var originalArray = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('Sheet1!A:F').getValues();
  var subarray = originalArray.map(e=>[e[4],e[0],e[3]]);
  originalArray = originalArray.map(e=>[e[1],e[2],e[5]]);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly

```
function rearrangeCols(data, orderFront, orderBack) {
  orderFront = orderFront.map(a => data[0].findIndex(s => s === a));
  orderBack  = orderBack.map(a => data[0].findIndex(s => s === a));

  let
    dataIdx  = data[0].map( x => data[0].indexOf(x)),
    remove   = [...orderFront,...orderBack],           
    newOrder = [...orderFront,
                ... dataIdx.filter(item => !remove.includes(item)),
                ...orderBack
               ];

  //Rearange data array
  data = data.map(a => newOrder.map(i => a[i]));
  
  return data;
}
```